# Truecrypt: Encrypt whole system on a mac

Tags: mac-osx, truecrypt

I it possible to encrypt the whole system partition of my mac using truecrypt. It seems to work for windows but I did not find a solution for my mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Truecrypt doesn't currently support system encryption on Mac OS X. Here is the list of OSes that currently support system encryption:

http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=sys-encryption-supported-os